# Error : BLOB/TEXT column 'multimedia' used in key specification without a key length

Tags: mysql, sql, navicat

I'm trying to create a table to store images,video, or audio, but get this error message:

"Error : BLOB/TEXT column 'multimedia' used in key specification without a key length"

```
Create Table Multimedia
(
uname varchar(25),
datetime timestamp,
multimedia blob,
primary key (uname,datetime,multimedia),
foreign key (uname) references Entry(uname),
foreign key (datetime) references Entry(datetime)
);
```

Does anyone know to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

As per documentation on [***`Prefixing INDEXes`***](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/column-indexes.html#idm47331033376832):

> When you index a `BLOB` or `TEXT` column, you must specify a prefix length
>   for the index.
>
> For example:
>
> `CREATE TABLE test ( blob_col BLOB, INDEX( blob_col( 10 ) ) );`
>
> Prefixes can be up to `1000` bytes long (`767` bytes for `InnoDB` tables,
>   unless you have `innodb_large_prefix` set).

Change your table `primary key` definition as below:

```
Create Table Multimedia
(
  uname varchar(25),
  datetime timestamp,
  multimedia blob,

  primary key ( uname, datetime, multimedia( 767 ) ), -- <--- changed

  foreign key ( uname ) references Entry( uname ),
  foreign key ( datetime ) references Entry( datetime )
);
```

You can also consider a design change to store `multimedia` object in a different table with a `unique` key on it and with a `auto increment` primary key number. And you can use the same `multimedia_id` in this table to form a primary key as like:

```
  primary key ( uname, datetime, multimedia_id ),
  foreign key ( uname ) references Entry( uname ),
  foreign key ( datetime ) references Entry( datetime ),
  foreign key ( multimedia_id ) references multimedia_objects( id )
```